# Google protocol buffers not found when trying to freeze python app

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

When trying to freeze python (2.7) application with any of cx_freeze, bbfreeze, pyinstaller or py2exe, the frozen application cannot find google.protobuf.

In logs of the freezing process there is usually something like 'cannot find google'. So the google package is not found and not packaged, although it's in python's site-packages and the non-frozen version works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've already had a solution when writing the question - I'm putting it here because it's probable that other people will find it here easily.

The solution: Create empty `__init__.py` in `Lib/site-packages/google` of your python installation directory, and compile it somehow (`import google` in interactive python session for example).
When there is `__init__.pyc` in the package directory, the freezing tools start to work.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. it is still relevant.